Is there a way to bypass type alias collisions
#Let's say we have:
A.h file:
 class A {}; 
 using name=A;

B.h file:
class B {}; 
using name=B; //meaning the alias same name

C.h file:
#include "A.h"
#include "B.h"

#Question:  +Will the 'name' collide in C.h file?  +And if yes, is there a way around to keep the 'name' for both classes in file C.h ? (assuming for creating generic code or whatever reason)
Please help.

What do you mean when you say "generic code"? Normally when the term "generic code" is used in a C++ context, one usually means templates.

As for the "collision" (which you have) the usual way to solve them is to use namespaces.

@Someprogrammerdude , i would vaguely imagine use the same name accessing the local functions (of each class) that are also has the same local name. not pretty sure, but that's what I thought would happen in Unreal Engine 5 (please correct me if I'm wrong)

@Someprogrammerdude , meaning we create namespace either in the source A.h or B.h file? :)

Why do you need both types (A and B) be called the same (name) and how did you intend to diffrentiate between them ?

@wohlstad oh, it is for very specific reason in UE5 , I got an idea from UE5 built-in that that use the same code to trigger different type in inheritence hierarchy: name1->name2->name3....->function() . using the very same name

Please include all the details, as well as the context, in the question itself.

By local functions, do you mean inside member functions of that same class? If so, wouldn't you want it inside the class definition rather than globally?

I wish I can describe it better, but I got lost while reading the code :)

+For example (just a small example) in UE5, they use 'Super:: ' and then we can include other sub classes, also has 'Super:: '
+which 'Super:: ' is alias of different sub-classes in the current file.
